# How to append a line to a specific block in a file with fs

Tags: node.js, node.js-fs

I need to append a line to a block inside a file with fs.
I have a file that has a block:

```js
dependencies {
  ...
}
```

I would like to add a line to this block with fs so it prints:

```js
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation files("../../node_modules/react-native-star-io10/android/src/lib/stario10.aar")
}
```

So I know I need to do something like this:

```js
fs.appendFile(fileToAppend, 'implementation files("../../node_modules/react-native-star-io10/android/src/lib/stario10.aar")', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

But this will append to the end of the file. How can I append to the end of the `dependencies` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only append to the end of a file.  You can't insert new data into the middle of a file.

If the file is not huge, then you would typically read the whole thing into memory, insert your data where you want it in memory, then write it all back out again.

If the file is JSON, then you can read the whole thing into memory, parse it into a Javascript object, then add the items you want to the relevant properties/objects in the Javascript object, then convert back to JSON and write it all back out.  If your data is JSON, this uses the JSON parser as your parser, saving you having to write any parsing code.

If the file is huge, you can stream it in a line at a time, parsing as you go.  As you go, you write out the data you read to a new file.  When you find the spot where you want to insert data, you write that new data out (to the new file) in the right place and then continue reading the rest of the file, writing it out as you go.  When, you're all done, you can delete the original and rename the new file back to the name  you want.  While this still involves reading and rewriting the entire file, it can be done a few lines at a time so you can handle any size huge file without using a lot of memory.

Here's an example of reading the file into memory, doing an in-memory replace to add new data and then writing it back out:

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function insertFileData(filename, regEx, dataToInsert) {
  const data = await fs.promises.readFile(filename, 'utf8');
  const newData = data.replace(regEx, "$&" + dataToInsert);
  return fs.promises.writeFile(filename, newData);
}

insertFileData("temp.txt", /[\n^]\s+dependencies\s+{\s*\n/, "  Additional data\n  More data\n").then(() => {
  console.log("Finished successfully");
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Sounds great actually. Could you please keep your comment as is, but show an example of your last paragraph with code, where I go line by line until I find `dependencies {` then add a line break with that line I need and end by overwriting the file with the updated data?

Comment: @Ben - I'd use the [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module to do the reading by line, create a writestream for the output and then upon each `line` event from readline, you see if you've found your dependencies line.  If not, just write the line out you got to the writestream.  If so, write it out, then add your new content.  Then, just finish copying the rest on all the rest of the `line` events.  I think you can write the code yourself and ask another question if you get stuck.

Comment: @Ben - Like I said, it's a lot less code if you can just read the whole file into memory and do a search and replace, then write it back out after modifying.